# How to join two query which first one is made up of two parts?

Tags: mysql, join

I have two query like these:

**Query1:**

```
SELECT id, title col2, content col3 FROM Posts1 WHERE title = :q

  UNION ALL

SELECT id, subject col2, description col3 FROM Posts2 WHERE Match (subject) AGAINST (:q)
```

The name of result table is `Posts3`.

Now I want to join `Posts3` with `Votes` table `ON Posts3.id = Votes.Posts_id`:

**Query2:**

```
SELECT id, sum(vote) From Votes
```

---

Well, how can I joint two above queries?

---

**Example:**

```
// Posts1                             // Posts2
+----+-------+---------------+        +----+---------+------------------+
| id | title |    content    |        | id | subject |    description   |
+----+-------+---------------+        +----+---------+------------------+
```

Suppose this is the result (`UNION ALL`) both `Posts1` and `Posts2`:

```
// Posts3                     
+----+-------+---------------+
| id | col2  |    col3       |
+----+-------+---------------+
```

Also I have a `Votes` table like this:

```
// Votes
+----+------+
| id | vote |
+----+------+
```

---

Now, I want to know, how can I `Posts3 JOIN Votes` ?

Comment: Join how new row/column? Be specific, share sample data and result

Comment: @lad2025 I don't get it..., usually there is one `Posts` table and one `Votes` table, but My question is about: having two `Posts` table ..

Comment: There is not posts_Id in Votes table that I can see in the above.  I assume you just mean ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the queries as derived tables/inline views... alias and treat them as tables.  So we aliased the query1 as posts3 and aliased query 2 as V

```
Select * 
from 
(SELECT id, title col2, content col3 
 FROM Posts1 
 WHERE title = :q
 UNION ALL
 SELECT id, subject col2, description col3 
 FROM Posts2 
 WHERE Match (subject) AGAINST (:q)) Posts3
INNER JOIN (Select ID, Sum(Vote) from votes) V
 on V.ID = Posts3.ID
```

There may be a way of combining the results without two separate queries which would result in better performance, but this does I believe answer the basic question.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I wanted. +1